# Adding a fade in animation to UIViewController appearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller

When I change `UIViewController` with this method, it just appears without any animation. I want to add a fade in animation to the view, how could I do that?

```
- (void)changeToRootViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController forNavigationController:(UINavigationController*)naviController class:(Class)class
{
    if ([[naviController.viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:[class class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Already inside %@.", NSStringFromClass(class));
        return;
    }

    [naviController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:naviController.viewControllers];
    [viewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    naviController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
    [naviController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with your mutation of the view controllers array?

Comment: To remove the first view controller and add the new one instead.

Comment: You are popping and pushing the view controller at the same time. This will result in Unbalanced animations.

Comment: Yeah, but the first one is without animation and the second one is with animation. What are you suggesting me to do instead? I have a `UINavigationController` with array of `UIViewControllers`, I want to remove all the `UIViewControllers` and than add one, this one I want to show in fade-in animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a single change to the navigation controller, not two:

```
[naviController setViewControllers:@[ viewController ] animated:YES];
```

which will replace the existing stack of controllers with your one controller, using the appropriate animation.

Assuming that you class check is really looking for the same instance rather than just the same class of view controller then you can actually replace all of this method with that one line.

If you want to leave some view controllers in the stack then create a mutable copy of the `viewControllers`, edit its contents and then set that array as the view `viewController` array, with animation.

Answer (score 7):

You can try something like this :

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;

[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:NO];
```